# Got a length error when replaying TPLOG in kdb

Tags: kdb

I got a length error when replaying tplog. Do you guys know what might cause this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A length error in a tickerplant is typically caused by a schema mismatch between the tickerplant config and what is being published by the feedhandler - specifically when the number of columns supplied doesn’t match the number specified in schema. If you want to find which update is causing the error, you could attempt to replay the log in a new session, e.g.

```
\l /path/to/schema.q
upd:{[t;x]t insert x}  / ensure upd is a lambda so we can error trap it
\e 1
-11!`:/path/to/logfile
```

This should stop when it gets to the offending message and allow you to examine it and see which table it comes from

Comment: when i change upd to your funciton i can replay the log without problem...so what was wrong ...

Comment: Could I ask what your original upd function was?